# Route value keeps staying the same

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3

In my .cshtml, I'm painting some data.  Then I have a repy textbox and a button for people to reply to a customer service thread.

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("Update", "CustomerServiceMessage", FormMethod.Post, new { id = 0 }))
    ...
}
```

When I submit, I don't get 0 when it hits my Update actionmethod, I get the id of the parent Service message I painted above the reply box.  So it's like an email/forum thread but even though I hard code the = 0 the Update method is getting an Id of the parent message that I painted on the screen (rendered).

Can't figure out why.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> When I submit, I don't get 0 when it hits my Update action method

That's normal, you never send this id to your server. You just used the [wrong overload](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd492714.aspx) of the `Html.BeginForm` helper:

```
@using (Html.BeginForm(
    "Update",                        // actionName
    "CustomerServiceMessage",        // controllerName
    FormMethod.Post,                 // method
    new { id = 0 }                   // htmlAttributes
))
{
    ...    
}
```

and you ended up with the following markup (assuming default routes):

```
<form id="0" method="post" action="/CustomerServiceMessage/Update">
    ...
</form>
```

See the problem?

And here's the [correct overload](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd492933.aspx):

```
@using (Html.BeginForm(
    "Update",                        // actionName
    "CustomerServiceMessage",        // controllerName
    new { id = 0 },                  // routeValues
    FormMethod.Post,                 // method
    new { @class = "foo" }           // htmlAttributes
))
{
    ...    
}
```

which generates (assuming default routes):

```
<form method="post" action="/CustomerServiceMessage/Update/0">
    ...
</form>
```

Now, you will get your `id=0` inside the corresponding controller action.

By the way you could make your code more readable and avoid this kind of mistakes by using [C# 4.0 named parameters](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd264739.aspx):

```
@using (Html.BeginForm(
    actionName: "Update", 
    controllerName: "CustomerServiceMessage", 
    routeValues: new { id = 0 }, 
    method: FormMethod.Post,
    htmlAttributes: new { @class = "foo" }
))
{
    ...    
}
```

Comment: thanks very much, you were right.  Now I didn't mention that originally I also had new {id = 0, class = "someClass"} and after I move this per your reply above I do get the 0 now and it works but I lose the formatting from class (css formatting).

Comment: @CoffeeAddict, then simply use the [correct overload](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd460542.aspx): `@using (Html.BeginForm("Update", "CustomerServiceMessage", new { id = 0 }, FormMethod.Post, new { @class = "foo" })) { ... }`. Don't you ever read the documentation? Or look at the Intellisense in Visual Studio which tells you the parameters of the method you are calling?

Comment: really appreciate your help today, good stuff here! learned a lot.